# OSX Cannot download files via browser

Tags: google-chrome, file-permissions, safari-5

On Chrome I get an immediate download failure

On Safari I get an error message saying I'm out of disk space although I have 26.48gb free

Recently I started emptying "cache" folders throughout my system to free up space and I'm thinking that messed up my permissions somehow so that browsers can't write to their respected temp folders. I already ran a permissions repair from disk utility and in `~/Library/Caches/Google` I change the permissions for "everyone" to read/write with no go.

What do I need to do so that I can download files from my browser again?

** EDIT **

- I do not use a virus scanner
- I'm currently having to downlad items via terminal like so:
  `curl "http://some.server/some.file" -o ~/some.file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was convinced this was going to be a caching issue, but it wasn't; It was a lot simpler than that.

My downloads folder is `ln -s` to my external hard drive and for whatever reason my drive had mounted as `read-only` so after I umounted/mounted the drive everything starting working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting your Safari and Chrome plist files?

Safari:

> mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ~/Desktop/

Chrome:

> mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist ~/Desktop/

Have you also tried resetting your permissions from the recovery partition, as well as disk repair?

Comment: I didn't try the recovery partition no but I found the issue. +1 for at least attempting to solve such a crazy sounding issue.

Comment: Would you mind appending the fix?

Comment: What do you mean? The mounted filesystem which contained my downloads folder was mounted as read-only. Remounting mounted the fs as read/write which inevitable fixed the issue. If I need to make that more clear let me know.